# The famous tag regex answer: Should its title be edited?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, title

I love [the famous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) by bobince regarding using regular expressions for parsing of text with HTML (and other markup) tags.

It is probably one of the most-linked <strike>questions</strike> answers on Stack Overflow.

However, seeing it linked to in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683046/regular-expression-for-extracting-script-tags) got me thinking. Is it linked so often because people asking related questions are not finding it because the title is a little too specific? ("RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags")?

If the title were "Using RegEx to match HTML tags" or even "Using RegEx to match tags" would people be more likely to come across it? I have a suspicion that "XHTML," "Open Tags," and "Self-contained" are keywords that might cause people to think it doesn't apply to their case.

Thoughts?

Comment: Just for the record, though I guess you know: it is *explicitly* linked, not just listed in the "related" list.

Comment: That’s not an answer; it’s a joke. In contrast, [*this* is an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4231382/471272).  ***Zalgo delenda est.***

Comment: "one of the most-linked questions answers". Probably. At the time of writing [about 7000 questions are linking to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/1732348?pagesize=50&sort=hot).

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**No**. Changing the title to something unrepresentative would only lead to more unhelpful links in unrelated questions.

Bobinces fun answer gets glorified on SO, but it is not very useful in itself. Notice how the question there was about parsing **nested** XHTML. There are many good technical answers on that page. The bobince answer isn't.

When people ask about "parsing" HTML, they mostly mean "extracting". And your linked example specifically does. If so, linking to bobince's answer is the most dis-social thing you could do. Because it doesn't apply. Regular expressions are very much sufficient to extract the contents of a single tag.

Changing the title of the question to suit the non-answer would make it easier to find, yes. But it's doubtful that this helps newbies - who don't search anyway. But it is highly likely that this would lead to more insolent links on only vaguely related questions.

Anyway, there was [another discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73133/regex-and-html-the-long-tail-annoys-me) about this two weeks ago.

Comment: I'm so happy that you mentions this.  Regex works great for parsing data out of given tags.  But if you even mention regex and html in the same sentence people's heads explode.

Comment: +1 because this is a very well thought-out answer and perfectly applicable. Also, because you mention that using a regex is perfectly acceptable for extracting the content of a single tag.

Comment: @JYelton: for the record: I do actually agree with your sentiment that every SO user should see the bobince answer once in their life. However it's meanwhile beyond meme status, and too often used as cargo cult programming advise. But of course better reference questions are also difficult to find.

Comment: @jjnguy Yes, the knee-jerk linking to this notoriously poor albeit tritely amusing non-answer is a serious problem, since it happens even when patterns are the best solution.  ***Zalgo delenda est.***

Comment: You start by having a regex extracting data given a single (leaf) tag.  OK.  But then it's tempting to just search that regex over the whole document — which is no longer OK, because `<!--` and CDATA and attributes/scripts/CSS that contain strings that contain something that looks like your tag...  The linked example uses "extracting" in the sense of *finding over the whole document*.  The linked example was about `<script` tags whose [termination rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#restrictions-for-contents-of-script-elements) are un̨ho͞ly even without regexes.  Zalgo applies.

Comment: OTOH, the OP in the linked example [was convinced](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683046/regular-expression-for-extracting-script-tags#comment5163887_4683106) by an answer with simple nesting counter-example and not(?) by the Zalgo link.  So yes, explaining why it fails is more friendly and might be more effective.  I just disagree bobince's answer is narrowly applicable to some *technical* needs — even when regex might work, it'll be buggy, insanely messy or both, and there is value in warning beginners to not even try and use a library.

Comment: If you only have one tag, you can just slice the string, which is also more efficient.

Comment: mario, nice to see someone here has a head on their shoulders to recognize how bobince's answer (while berated by many) is really, lacking substance.  Parse, and extract are very similar, but what they complain mostly is they can't build an engine that understands the depth of html in regex. You can definitely parse or extract data. To `parse` is to break language/text into smaller components. The 'cthulu' rant, is obnoxious and not a professional answer.

Comment: @jjnguy Our heads explode because it's far more sensitive to random changes in the text. You don't query JSON using regex. You pass it through a parser and access the object or use something like JsonPath (which knows how to parse the structure). For HTML, you can use JavaScript's `getElementsByTagName` or jQuery or libraries like BeautifulSoup to access the elements and work with the structure, instead of pretending it doesn't exist and writing code that makes no sense and probably will fail one day. Even if it works now, it's still hammering a nail with the wide end of a screwdriver.

Comment: While It's true that regex may be OK at times, the reasoning with "just single tag" is not very accurate.  The issue is that with regex you get "single tag that looks like this" but normally what you really want is tag that "means this thing" -- the structure, not the looks is what defines the meaning, so your application will break (possibly in a *very **horrible*** way) once someone adds tag that also happens to "look like that".  Again, people will get away with it as long as they only use trivial and stable ML structures.

Answer (score 8):

While I agree that the title should be changed if you want to receive better search hits on the answer, I don't think that the answer is a very good one to help out people looking to parse HTML.

Its message has become obscured in the fame and theatrics of the answer.  I think there are better answers out there to the question "How can I parse HTML with Regex?"

Comment: Aye, [there's a lot of thought](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73133/regex-and-html-the-long-tail-annoys-me) that as truthful and memetic as the answer is, to people who aren't "in" it's just unhelpful. It may start off with the literal "You can't", which is what makes it still an answer, but it's very likely that inexperienced users will just be put off by its length.

Comment: I agree, the "famous answer" isn't actually that helpful to a new user, while the more experienced community finds it humorous. That said, there are other answers and comments on that thread that might get a new user on the right track.

Comment: @jye, I think that answer is far to distracting.

Comment: Y'all are stuffy elitists. I learned everything I know about parsing HTML with regex from reading that answer. Also, Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Tony R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn.

Comment: @Shog, I disagree - O͇̹̺ͅƝ̴ȳ̳ TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝

Comment: The accepted answer with 4k upvotes that starts "You can't parse [X]HTML with regex." is perfectly clear, the rest of the post demonstrates that "that way madness lies". I was a dev with half a year's experience when I first read it linked from a Coding Horror blog and I fully understood its message.

Comment: @Stuper, I'm not arguing that it can't be helpful.  I'm just arguing that there are much better ways to present that information.

Comment: That's very true.

Comment: @GraceNote It is not all that truthful, and it is certainly not helpful or useful. I would like to see it deleted, and if not deleted, that a permablock set up to stop people from linking it it.  ***Zalgo delenda est.***

Comment: @jinguy One of the reasons that it is so helpful is that it's unforgettable. It gives the correct answer, namely, "you can't / should not even attempt to", and then discusses the theoretical knowledge behind the answer in a humorous way that gets people who would not otherwise be interested in said theory to learn and remember it.

Answer (score 8):

I'd rather it be kept as-is so that it's more authentic.